# I am having problem resetting the location of the canvas when I zoom in to multiple points

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to understand how scaling the Tkinter canvas works, but I am having trouble fixing the issue. In the following code, there is a rectangle on a canvas that I can move and zoom in and out, along with a reset position button. I want to reset the location and scale of the canvas to the original location when it was initialized. I was able to get it to work, but only if I zoom in or out from a fixed point. So, if I keep the mouse in one point, zoom in, then move and reset, it works. Similarly, if I do the same with zooming out, it works. However, it breaks when I try to zoom in or out to multiple points. I could not figure out what the problem is. This is the full code.

```
import tkinter as tk



class CanvasWithAbsolutePosition(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.current_position = [0, 0]
        self.initial_position = [0, 0]
        self.current_scale = 1.0  # Current scale factor

        # Create a rectangle on the canvas
        self.rectangle = self.create_rectangle(0, 0, 150, 150, fill="blue")

        # Bind the events for dragging the canvas
        self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_canvas_click)
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_drag)

        # Bind the event for zooming with the mouse wheel
        self.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.on_mouse_wheel)

        self.universal_scale = 1

    def on_canvas_click(self, event):
        # Get the current position of the rectangle
        self.initial_rect_position = self.coords(self.rectangle)[:2]

        # Update the initial position when clicked
        self.initial_position[0] = event.x
        self.initial_position[1] = event.y
    def on_drag(self, event):
        # Calculate the movement during dragging
        movement_x = event.x - self.initial_position[0]
        movement_y = event.y - self.initial_position[1]

        # Move the rectangle along with the canvas
        self.move(self.rectangle, movement_x, movement_y)

        # Update the current position
        self.current_position[0] += movement_x
        self.current_position[1] += movement_y

        # Update the initial position for the next drag event
        self.initial_position[0] = event.x
        self.initial_position[1] = event.y

    def on_mouse_wheel(self, event):
        # Zoom in or out based on the direction of the mouse wheel

        scale_factor = 1.2  # You can adjust this value to control the zooming speed
        zoom_scale = 1
        if event.delta > 0:
            self.current_scale *= scale_factor
            self.scale("all", event.x, event.y, scale_factor, scale_factor)
            zoom_scale = scale_factor
        else:
            self.current_scale /= scale_factor
            self.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 1 / scale_factor, 1 / scale_factor)
            zoom_scale = 1 / scale_factor

        movement_x = (event.x * self.universal_scale -  event.x * self.universal_scale  * zoom_scale)
        movement_y = (event.y * self.universal_scale -  event.y * self.universal_scale  * zoom_scale)

        self.universal_scale = zoom_scale * self.universal_scale

        # Update the current position
        self.current_position[0] += movement_x
        self.current_position[1] += movement_y

        # Update the initial position for the next drag event
        self.initial_position[0] = event.x
        self.initial_position[1] = event.y

        print(f"Current Canvas Position: {tuple(self.current_position)}")
    def reset_canvas_position(self):
        # Calculate the reverse movement to bring the canvas back to (0, 0)
        reverse_movement_x = -self.current_position[0]
        reverse_movement_y = -self.current_position[1]

        # Reset the current position to 0, 0
        self.current_position = [0, 0]
        print("Canvas Reset to (0, 0)")

        # Reset the scale to 1.0
        scale_factor = 1 / self.current_scale
        self.current_scale = 1.0

        # Scale and move the rectangle back to its initial position
        self.scale("all", -reverse_movement_x, -reverse_movement_y, scale_factor, scale_factor)
        self.move(self.rectangle, reverse_movement_x, reverse_movement_y)

        # Update the initial position of the rectangle
        self.initial_position = [0, 0]
        self.universal_scale = 1


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = CanvasWithAbsolutePosition(root, width=400, height=300, scrollregion=(0, 0, 800, 600))
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

reset_button = tk.Button(root, text="Reset Canvas", command=canvas.reset_canvas_position)
reset_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I think the problem is that the scaling is changing when I move the mouse but I cant seem to understand how to implement that in to my code.

Comment: In addition to the figure, you also need to return the canvas to its place. https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas-window-coords.html